# Adding text values to dynamically create text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Here is everything and I tried to put a suggestion in and it sort of works on the changing the color of the row but it only changes it once, every row after stays as the .odd background color.

Basically I am trying to add row dynamically, which works, mask the input text fields, which works, take the value from the `endtime_1` and put it in the `starttime_2(dynamic add)` of the next added row when the `addrow()` button is clicked. Then take the value of `endtime_2(dynamic add)` and put it in `starttime_3(dynamic add)` when the `addrow()` button is clicked, and so on and so on and so on.... That isn't working. I would like to also color each of the odd numbered rows with the background styling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function maskInput(){
    $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
    $(".time").mask("99:99 aa");

    $("input").blur(function() {
        $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
    }).dblclick(function() {
        $(this).unmask();
    });
}
var clone;
function cloneRow(){
    var rows=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var index=rows.length-1;
    clone=rows[index-0].cloneNode(true);
    if (index % 2 !=0) { $(clone).addClass("odd"); }
    var inputs=clone.getElementsByTagName('input'), inp, i=0,n ;
    while(inp=inputs[i++]){
        inp.name=inp.name.replace(/\d/g,'')+(index+1);
        $('#starttime_'+index).attr('value',$('#endtime_'+index-1).attr('value'));
    }
    var select=clone.getElementsByTagName('select'), sel, i=0,n ;
    while(sel=select[i++]){
        sel.name=sel.name.replace(/\d/g,'')+(index+1);
    }
    maskInput();
    }
    function addRow(){
        var tbo=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        tbo.appendChild(clone);
        cloneRow();
    }
    function checkDOM(){
        var rows=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        alert(rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].name);
    }
}
onload=cloneRow;
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.odd { background-color:#CCC; }
</style>

<table border='0' id='TimeCard' width='950'>
<tr class="odd">
    <td align="left" width="100"><b><i><u>Select Type</u></i></b></td>
        <td align="left" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="100"><b><i><u>Select Property</u></i></b></td>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="100"><b><i><u>Start Time</u></i></b></td>
        <td align="left" width="100"><b><i><u>End Time</u></i></b></td>
        <td align="left" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td align="left" width="100">
        <select name="type_1" id="type_1" class="validate[required]">
            <option selected value=''> -- Please Select -- </option>
            <option value="office">Office</option>
            <option value="work">Working</option>
            <option value="drive">Driving</option>
            <option value="break">Break</option>
            <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
            <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    </select>
        </td>
        <td align="left" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="100">
        <select name="propid_1" id="propid_1" class="validate[required]">
            <option selected value=''> -- Please Select -- </option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" width="100"><input type="text" class="time" id="starttime_1" name="starttime_1" size="10" /></td>
    <td align="left" width="100"><input type="text" class="time" id="endtime_1" name="endtime_1" size="10" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="20"><input type="button" value=' + ' onclick='addRow();' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why are you using `getElementById` if you used jQuery

Comment: Try indenting your code, it helps it become more readable. Also, post some sample/representative HTML. And, if possible, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo would be useful. @mgraph: if you don't need the jQuery methods, native JavaScript performs more efficiently. It's not always a bad thing.

Comment: @David Thomas Sorry about the no indent. It was and now it should be again. the HTML table is posted with everything else so not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

color the table rows in pure css:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#CCC;}
```

Otherwise, please ask a targeted question.